# Check the error in the hive udf written in python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I have written a hive udf using python but while running my query using udf. I am getting the following error in the logs-

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing
>   operators: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the
>   Operator running your custom script.

How can I check the error where my python script is breaking up, as the map reduce logs just show me the error in the job as shown above.

Comment: Which client are you using for querying? beeline?

Comment: yes, I am using beeline and its a python udf

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your query using UDF as

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -e "query"
```

And check log file created in logs folder. It will be a detailed log. Make sure that logs folder exist before executing the command.